# How package node addon into asar archive with electron-packager?

Tags: node.js, electron, electron-packager, asar

How can I add node addon (which is used in renderer process!) into asar archive with electron-packager? Webpack generate files:

```
./dist
    bundle.js
    addon.node
    index.html
    main.css
```

And then after:

```
electron-packager ./ --out=./builds --asar --platform=win32 --arch=x64
```

I don't have addon.node in asar archive.

Answer (score 0):

I tried reproducing the issue but my .node file and electron-packager v12.1.1 and saw that my addon.node file was still correctly in the asar archive. 
How are you checking that the asar archive doesn't contain your addon.node file?
I ran `asar extract app.asar` to find my node.

Maybe try electron-packager with the --no-prune flag. If your package is required through your devDependencies, then it will be pruned by default.